# Calculate time complexity for Distinct Subsequences

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Question is from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/distinct-subsequences/), I came up with below code, but i have a hard time to find out it time complexity. any idea how to calculate its time complexity? (what if without the Dictionary memory)

```
        public int NumDistinct (string s, string t)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (s) && string.IsNullOrEmpty (t))
                return 1;
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (s) || string.IsNullOrEmpty (t))
                return 0;

            return FindSequences (s, 0, t, 0);
        }

        Dictionary<string, int> memoery = new Dictionary<string, int> ();

        private int FindSequences (string s, int idxs, string t, int idxt)
        {
            if (idxt == t.Length)
                return 1;
            else if (idxs == s.Length)
                return 0;

            string key = string.Format ("{0}-{1}", idxs, idxt);
            if (memoery.ContainsKey (key))
                return memoery [key];

            int result = 0;
            if (s [idxs] == t [idxt]) {
                result = FindSequences (s, idxs + 1, t, idxt + 1) + FindSequences (s, idxs + 1, t, idxt);
            } else {
                result = FindSequences (s, idxs + 1, t, idxt);
            }
            memoery.Add (key, result);
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity here is `O(SizeOf(s) * SizeOf(t))`. In case of `Dynamic Programming Solutions`, you can calculate Time complexity using the amount of different states you have, here the amount of states is `SizeOf(s) * sizeOf(t)`.

Dynamic Programming uses the concept of `Memoisation` i.e storing the result of a state so that it can be used when we encounter the same state, so effectively we do not do redundant calculations, as states often repeat and when they do we use the results calculated before to reduce the Time Complexity.

Also note that The time complexity also depends on the `Look up table` or `DP Table` which in the above case is a `Dictionary`, so you also have to factor in the time of `Dictionary Look up` and `Dictionary Insertion`, effectively making the complexity to be :

`O(SizeOf(s) * SizeOf(t) * Time to look Up or insert in Dictionary)`.

Comment: what if we remove the "Dictionary<string, int> memoery", what is the time complexity?

Comment: Since you are removing the `memoisation step`, the time complexity would become `Exponential` i.e. `O(2 ^ SizeOf(t))`

Comment: In the worst case : At every step of the recursive call, you can make 2 decisions i.e. either to include the current alphabet of the string `t` in the answer or not, you do this by either increasing the `idxt` variable by one or keeping it the same, so you have `2 ^ n` possible ways of generating the search space, where `n` is the size of string `t`.